# How to stop a PowerShell script on the first error?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want my PowerShell script to stop when any of the commands I run fail (like `set -e` in bash). I'm using both Powershell commands (`New-Object System.Net.WebClient`) and programs (`.\setup.exe`).

Comment: See also [Equivalent of bash `set -e` · Issue #3415 · PowerShell/PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3415).

Comment: In PowerShell [7.3.0-preview.1](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.3.0-preview.1), set `$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference` to `$true` and `$ErrorActionPreference` to `'Stop'` can stop the script execution when native command error occurs. Test code: `& { $PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference = $true; $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; ping.exe bbb; ping.exe aaa }` .

Answer (score 480, accepted):

`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` will get you part of the way there (i.e. this works great for cmdlets).

However for EXEs you're going to need to check `$LastExitCode` yourself after every exe invocation and determine whether that failed or not. Unfortunately I don't think PowerShell can help here because on Windows, EXEs aren't terribly consistent on what constitutes a "success" or "failure" exit code.  Most follow the UNIX standard of 0 indicating success but not all do. Check out the [CheckLastExitCode function in this blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/effective-powershell-item-16-dealing-with-errors/). You might find it useful.

Comment: Does `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` work for well-behaved programs (that return 0 on success)?

Comment: No, it doesn't work at all for EXEs.  It only works for PowerShell cmdlets which run in-process.  It is kind of pain but you have to check $LastExitCode after every EXE invocation, check that against the expected exit code and if that test indicates failure, you have to throw to terminate execution of the script e.g. `throw "$exe failed with exit code $LastExitCode"` where $exe is just the path to the EXE.

Comment: note that psake has a commandlet called "exec" which can you can use to wrap calls to external programs with a check for LastExitCode and display an error (and stop, if desired)

Comment: If you should discover something is bad and want to stop your program (which is why I found this page), then you should know that "Exit" is the command you're looking for.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something. For `Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $NodeAddress` where `$NodeAddress` is invalid the script execution does not stop even PS throws the error _Connect-IscsiTarget : The target name is not found or is marked as hidden from login._. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: but!: be **careful to maybe reset the `ErrorActionPreference` finally since it overwrites it globally!** `$oldEap = $ErrorActionPreference ; $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" ; try { ... } finally { $ErrorActionPreference = $oldEap }` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15546666/1915920

Comment: Within a script, setting `$ErrorActionPreference` impacts only the rest of the script and doesn't override the `global session` value of this variable.  Well, unless you set the variable like this: `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.

Comment: @Keith Hill: but not if you source it (what I do a lot and maybe others) via `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue" ; . ./subscript.ps1 ; echo "$ErrorActionPreference"` (and *subscript.ps1* will set it to `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` it will output `stop`! So it still seems a good practice to me.

Comment: actually `$oldEap` from my previous comment can be bad if this variable is used in a parent/ancestor script that dot sourced the child/descendants. I am not sure if "$local:oldEap = ..." would help here (which I doubt).

Comment: Many years later, there's now an [RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/88/files) for introducing abort-on-failure support for external programs too.

Comment: Got caught by this too :S To me this makes PS unusable for buildscripts in CI, that need to exit on whatever first error - I don't wanna have to remember to wrap every single external cmd in `exec`. Running away quickly to `bash -e`

Comment: If you only use PS commands, the Parameter `erroraction` with value `stop` would suffice.

Comment: Note that there are some buggy cmdlets that cause this to not work 100% of the time. See my answer below for the additional things you want to do (`Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` and `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ErrorAction']='Stop'`)

Comment: `The term '​' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` Got this error after adding this. any idea about the error?

Comment: @JustWe I suggest you look at the detailed error info to determine the line in your script that is failing.  To see this, execute `$error[0] | fl * -force` right after the script has failed.

Answer (score 96):

You should be able to accomplish this by using the statement `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at the beginning of your scripts.

The default setting of `$ErrorActionPreference` is `Continue`, which is why you are seeing your scripts keep going after errors occur.

Comment: This does not affect programs, only cmdlets.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer, however it was posted prior to the currently selected answer which builds on it. So it deserve its upvotes too, imho.

Comment: "at the beginning of your scripts" <- after the param block

Comment: With the release of powershell 7.4.0, `PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference` is [enabled by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.4#psnativecommanderroractionpreference), so `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` will stop execution even for native programs 

Answer (score 57):

Sadly, [due to buggy cmdlets like New-RegKey and Clear-Disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245579), none of these answers are enough. I've currently settled on the following code in a file called `ps_support.ps1`:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ErrorAction']='Stop'
function ThrowOnNativeFailure {
    if (-not $?)
    {
        throw 'Native Failure'
    }
}
```

Then in any powershell file, after the `CmdletBinding` and `Param` for the file (if present), I have the following:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
. "$PSScriptRoot\ps_support.ps1"
```

The duplicated `ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` line is intentional. If I've goofed and somehow gotten the path to `ps_support.ps1` wrong, that needs to not silently fail!

I keep `ps_support.ps1` in a common location for my repo/workspace, so the path to it for the dot-sourcing may change depending on where the current `.ps1` file is.

Any native call gets this treatment:

```
native_call.exe
ThrowOnNativeFailure
```

Having that file to dot-source has helped me maintain my sanity while writing powershell scripts. :-)

Answer (score 22):

A slight modification to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999101/516433) from @alastairtree:

```
function Invoke-Call {
    param (
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock,
        [string]$ErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
    )
    & @ScriptBlock
    if (($lastexitcode -ne 0) -and $ErrorAction -eq "Stop") {
        exit $lastexitcode
    }
}

Invoke-Call -ScriptBlock { dotnet build . } -ErrorAction Stop
```

The key differences here are:

1. it uses the Verb-Noun (mimicing `Invoke-Command`)
2. implies that it uses the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6) under the covers
3. *mimics* `-ErrorAction` behavior from built in cmdlets
4. exits with same exit code rather than throwing exception with new message

Comment: How do you pass parameters / variables? e.g. `Invoke-Call { dotnet build $something } `

Comment: @MichaelBlake the inquiry of yours is so right, allowing a params passthrough would make this approach gold. I am inspecting https://adamtheautomator.com/pass-hashtables-invoke-command-argument/ to adjust the Invoke-Call to support params pass-through. If I succeed, I will post it as another answer here.

Comment: Why do you use the splatting operator during the invoke? What does that get you? `& @ScriptBlock` and `& $ScriptBlock` appear to do the same thing. Haven't been able to google what the difference is in this case

Answer (score 17):

You need slightly different error handling for powershell functions and for calling exe's, and you need to be sure to tell the caller of your script that it has failed. Building on top of `Exec` from the library Psake, a script that has the structure below will stop on all errors, and is usable as a base template for most scripts.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"


# Taken from psake https://github.com/psake/psake
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  This is a helper function that runs a scriptblock and checks the PS variable $lastexitcode
  to see if an error occcured. If an error is detected then an exception is thrown.
  This function allows you to run command-line programs without having to
  explicitly check the $lastexitcode variable.
.EXAMPLE
  exec { svn info $repository_trunk } "Error executing SVN. Please verify SVN command-line client is installed"
#>
function Exec
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=1)][scriptblock]$cmd,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=0)][string]$errorMessage = ("Error executing command {0}" -f $cmd)
    )
    & $cmd
    if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) {
        throw ("Exec: " + $errorMessage)
    }
}

Try {

    # Put all your stuff inside here!

    # powershell functions called as normal and try..catch reports errors 
    New-Object System.Net.WebClient

    # call exe's and check their exit code using Exec
    Exec { setup.exe }

} Catch {
    # tell the caller it has all gone wrong
    $host.SetShouldExit(-1)
    throw
}
```

Comment: Invoking eg: `Exec { sqlite3.exe -bail some.db "$SQL" }`, the `-bail` causes an error since it's trying to interpret it as a Cmdlet parameter? Wrapping things in quotes doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to put this code somewhere central so you can do some kind of #include when you want to use the Exec method?

Comment: Yeah, you can. You can put it a file named `powershell-error-handling-sanity.ps1`  and then dot-source the ps1 file at t he top of any other ps1 file with `. <relative_or_absolute_path_to_powershell-error-handling-sanity.ps1`

Answer (score 16):

I'm new to powershell but this seems to be most effective:

```
doSomething -arg myArg
if (-not $?) {throw "Failed to doSomething"}
```

Answer (score 7):

for people coming here on 2021 this is my solution that covers both cmdlets and programs

```
function CheckLastExitCode {
    param ([int[]]$SuccessCodes = @(0))

    if (!$?) {
        Write-Host "Last CMD failed $LastExitCode" -ForegroundColor Red
        #GoToWrapperDirectory in my code I go back to the original directory that launched the script
        exit
    }

    if ($SuccessCodes -notcontains $LastExitCode) {
        Write-Host "EXE RETURNED EXIT CODE $LastExitCode" -ForegroundColor Red
        #GoToWrapperDirectory in my code I go back to the original directory that launched the script
        exit
    } 
    
}
```

you can use it like this

```
cd NonExistingpath
CheckLastExitCode
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Powershell does not have any automatic handling of non-zero exit codes returned by sub-programs it invokes.

The only solution I know about so far to mimick the behavior of `bash -e` is to add this check after *every* call to an external command:

```
if(!$?) { Exit $LASTEXITCODE }
```

Comment: I like this solution, it's just one line to add after each external program call.

Comment: @bounav: Well, this is relative. Let's just say it's the "less worse" solution I've found. On the other hand in a bash script you just add `#!/bin/bash -e` at the beginning of each script and it applies to the whole script all the time. I really really hate Powershell just for that stupid error handling. (But unfortunately I don't have much choice using it sometimes...)

Comment: I can't believe it's almost 2024 and I need to add this ugly little block of code after every single *.exe call in my deployment script just to get it to ACTUALLY fail in Azure DevOps when sc.exe gives a non-zero return code installing a Windows service! There are more elegant ways for me to solve this problem, but they seem to have taken 4+ years of community debate and have not yet left the experimental phase, let alone become available in a default Windows Server 2022 image running PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: Well, in the specific context of CI systems, there are some kind of solutions.

First of in both Azure Devops and Github Actions you can actually use bash on Windows if you want (example doc for Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines ). I think they both use git bash, which is kind of nice. Of course it's equivalent to just throwing away Powershell (a quite sane approach in my opinion).

Comment: Also on Gitlab CI, which I use professionally, while it doesn't have bash support on Windows (I tried) it does use some kind of magic on top of powershell to add automatic script stopping on errors, thus making powershell equivalent to a `bash -e`. (Don't ask me how they do that.) Not a bad solution either in the end (although I would prefer to be able to use bash on windows).

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for the same thing.  $ErrorActionPreference="Stop" kills my shell immediately when I'd rather see the error message (pause) before it terminates.  Falling back on my batch sensibilities:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 pause & GOTO EOF
```

I found that this works pretty much the same for my particular ps1 script:

```
Import-PSSession $Session
If ($? -ne "True") {Pause; Exit}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like simple rethrow does the trick.

```
param ([string] $Path, [string] $Find, [string] $Replace)
try {
  ((Get-Content -path $Path -Raw) -replace $Find, $Replace) | Set-Content -Path $Path
  Write-Output Completed.
} catch {
  # Without try/catch block errors don't interrupt program flow.
  throw
}
```

Now output *Completed* appears only after successful execution.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` seems to also do the trick without any other commands/scriptblock wrappers although I can't find an explanation why it works that way..

```
# test.ps1

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

aws s3 ls s3://xxx
echo "==> pass"

aws s3 ls s3://xxx 2>&1
echo "shouldn't be here"
```

This will output the following as expected (the command `aws s3 ...` returns `$LASTEXITCODE = 255`)

```
PS> .\test.ps1

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
==> pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use a helper function like this to invoke any "classic" binaries (.exe) that don't throw errors/exceptions that powershell understands:

```
function _(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$exe, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$True)][string[]]$arguments
) {
    &$exe @arguments
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "ERROR running '$exe $(($arguments) -join ' ')' failed with LASTEXITCODE=$LASTEXITCODE" }
}

# usage:
_ python --version
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to apply simple exit code validation. Depends on how sophisticated solution you need.

Best for single validation - stops only when docker-compose fails:

```
docker-compose up --detach || exit 1
```

Good if you want to stop the script and propagate error message

```
docker-compose up --detach || throw "Script has failed, check logs above"
```

or more complex and reusable function:

```
function terminate() {
    Write-Error "Found exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"
    throw "Last executed operation has failed, check logs above!"
}

docker-compose up --detach || terminate
```