# Failing postman collection due to assertion not resulting in jenkins failure

Tags: automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing, newman

I am running batch of collections via newman out of which few are failing due to assertion error. So I expect jenkins job to have unstable status at the end because of assertion failures but instead jenkins job is throwing success status.

How can I update Jenkins status to provide unstable status if any collection fails due to assertion error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you implemented your job but when I configured Jenkins it worked as expected. In your Jenkins job use **Execute shell** build step with following command:

```
newman run test.postman_collection.json
```

Newman will return 0 exit code on success and job will be green. On failure exit code will be 1 and job will fail.

Comment: i did in the similar fashion except that I am running multiple collections sequentially via powershell script. and out of those multple collections - few are failing due to assertion error but resulting in jenkins success status.

Comment: hmm, i think the issue is not with newman, but powershell script executing on jenkins. never ran powershell script in job, but from what i can see you need to configure powershell script execution on jenkins. take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349333/jenkins-powershell-plugin-always-builds-successfully

Comment: Thank you for the link. It helped me to proceed further and I could implement a solution to achieve what i need.