# Powershell script to install font family

Tags: windows, powershell

Below is my script istalling Monserrat fonts from zip file. I can't figure how to check if a font already installed. After installation I can open folder C:\Windows\Fonts\Montserrat and I see al of them. When I am running script second time, it is not recognize existance of this folder. Where is my mistake?

```
$Source = "Montserrat.zip"
$FontsFolder = "FontMontserrat"
Expand-Archive $Source -DestinationPath $FontsFolder
$FONTS = 0x14
$CopyOptions = 4 + 16;
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($FONTS)
$allFonts = dir $FontsFolder
foreach($File in $allFonts)
{
    If((Test-Path "C:\Windows\Fonts\Montserrat") -eq $True)
    {
        echo "Font $File already installed"
    }
    Else
    {
        echo "Installing $File"
        $CopyFlag = [String]::Format("{0:x}", $CopyOptions);
        $objFolder.CopyHere($File.fullname,$CopyFlag)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're on Windows 10, fonts are not installed into a folder, so your check is incorrect.  Also, the location is privileged so you need to ensure powershell is running as admin.

Comment: Modify your code so `$allFonts = dir c:\windows\fonts | select -expand Name` then instead of `Test-Path`, you can use `if($allFonts -contains $file.Name){...` to check if the font is installed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrections of your script based on my comment *assuming Windows 10*:

```
# well-known SID for admin group
if ('S-1-5-32-544' -notin [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups) {
    throw 'Script must run as admin!'
}

$source = 'Montserrat.zip'
$fontsFolder = 'FontMontserrat'

Expand-Archive -Path $source -DestinationPath $fontsFolder

foreach ($font in Get-ChildItem -Path $fontsFolder -File) {
    $dest = "C:\Windows\Fonts\$font"
    if (Test-Path -Path $dest) {
        "Font $font already installed."
    }
    else {
        $font | Copy-Item -Destination $dest
    }
}
```

Comment: Great help!!! One more question: how to run ps1 as administrator? I used cmd script to run it.

Comment: @ArkadyKarasin Look for "self-elevating script".  There are many examples here on SO, but nothing immediately comes to mind.

Comment: This does not work. Copying a font file into "C:\Windows\Fonts" does not install the font.

Answer (score 2):

Finally my script:

```
$Source = "Montserrat.zip"
$FontsFolder = "FontMontserrat"
Expand-Archive $Source -DestinationPath $FontsFolder -Force
$FONTS = 0x14
$CopyOptions = 4 + 16;
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($FONTS)
$allFonts = dir $FontsFolder
foreach($font in Get-ChildItem -Path $fontsFolder -File)
{
    $dest = "C:\Windows\Fonts\$font"
    If(Test-Path -Path $dest)
    {
        echo "Font $font already installed"
    }
    Else
    {
        echo "Installing $font"
        $CopyFlag = [String]::Format("{0:x}", $CopyOptions);
        $objFolder.CopyHere($font.fullname,$CopyFlag)
    }
}
```

I am running this script by following cmd:

```
set batchPath=%~dp0
powershell.exe -noexit -file "%batchPath%InstMontserrat.ps1"
```

I don't have to run it as administrator, but user have admin permissions.

Comment: This works. Note that on Windows 10 20H2, even in an elevated prompt, the above code installs my font into my local application data folder: `~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to install the font on OS level but only make it available for programs to use until reboot you may want to use this script that:

- Will fail/throw if it cannot register/unregister font.
- Broadcasts WM_FONTCHANGE to inform all windows that fonts have changed
- Does not require administrator privileges
- Does not install fonts in Windows, only makes them available for all programs in current session until reboot
- Has verbose mode for debugging
- Does not work with font folders

Usage:

```
register-fonts.ps1 [-v] [-unregister <PATH>[,<PATH>...]] [-register  <PATH>[,<PATH>...]] # Register and unregister at same time
register-fonts.ps1 [-v] -unregister <PATH>
register-fonts.ps1 [-v] -register <PATH>
register-fonts.ps1 [-v] <PATH> # Will register font path
```

```
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [String[]]$register,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [String[]]$unregister
)

# Stop script if command fails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948517/how-to-stop-a-powershell-script-on-the-first-error
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

add-type -name Session -namespace "" -member @"
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool AddFontResource(string filePath);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool RemoveFontResource(string filePath);
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam = 0, int lParam = 0);
"@

$broadcast = $False;
Foreach ($unregisterFontPath in $unregister) {
  Write-Verbose "Unregistering font $unregisterFontPath"
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-removefontresourcea
  $success = [Session]::RemoveFontResource($unregisterFontPath)
  if (!$success) {
    Throw "Cannot unregister font $unregisterFontPath"
  }
  $broadcast = $True
}

Foreach ($registerFontPath in $register) {
  Write-Verbose "Registering font $registerFontPath"
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcea
  $success = [Session]::AddFontResource($registerFontPath)
  if (!$success) {
    Throw "Cannot register font $registerFontPath"
  }
  $broadcast = $True
}

if ($broadcast) {
  # HWND_BROADCAST https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea
  $HWND_BROADCAST = New-Object IntPtr 0xffff
  # WM_FONTCHANGE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-fontchange
  $WM_FONTCHANGE  = 0x1D

  Write-Verbose "Broadcasting font change"
  # Broadcast will let other programs know that fonts were changed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea
  $success = [Session]::PostMessage($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_FONTCHANGE)
  if (!$success) {
    Throw "Cannot broadcase font change"
  }
}
```

The script was inspired by this gist https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/d53a16ce5e7d50b13530acb4f98aaabd

Comment: It would be nice to have an option to disable broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

I will share the script that I use. There are some steps that need to occur first. ***Note: This script has been tested in Dev, deployed to Pilot, then Prod. in our environment.***

1. for Montserrat font. I copied all of the .ttf files into the same directory (instead of the sub folder where most of the fonts were).
2. Saved the "Install-Font.ps1" into the same directory as the fonts.
3. To test locally:
4. Open PowerShell (as admin) and CD into the fonts folder.
5. Run the script to load the Install-Font function
6. PS C:\Temp\SoftwareDeploy\Fonts> .\Install-Font.ps1
7. PS C:\Temp\SoftwareDeploy\Fonts> Install-Font

   ```
    function Install-Font {
    param (
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$fontFile
    )
    try {
        $gt = [Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface]::new($fontFile.FullName)
        $family = $gt.Win32FamilyNames['en-us']
        if ($null -eq $family) {
            $family = $gt.Win32FamilyNames.Values.Item(0)
        }
        $face = $gt.Win32FaceNames['en-us']
        if ($null -eq $face) {
            $face = $gt.Win32FaceNames.Values.Item(0)
        }
        $fontName = ("$family $face").Trim()
        switch ($fontFile.Extension) {
            ".ttf" {$fontName = "$fontName (TrueType)"}
        }

        write-host "Installing font: $fontFile with font name '$fontName'"

        If (!(Test-Path ("$($env:windir)\\Fonts\\" + $fontFile.Name))) {
            write-host "Copying font: $fontFile"
            Copy-Item -Path $fontFile.FullName -Destination ("$($env:windir)\\Fonts\\" + $fontFile.Name) -Force
            write-host "Fonts have been copied into the Fonts directory"
        } else {
            write-host "Font already exists: $fontFile"
        }

        If (!(Get-ItemProperty -Name $fontName -Path "HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            write-host "Registering font: $fontFile"
            New-ItemProperty -Name $fontName -Path "HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts" -PropertyType string -Value $fontFile.Name -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
            Write-Host "Fonts have been registered successfully"
        } else {
            write-host "Font already registered: $fontFile"
        }

        } catch {
            write-host "Error installing font: $fontFile. " $_.exception.message
        }
    }

    $FontItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot | Where-Object {($_.Name -like '*.ttf')}

    foreach ($FontItem in $FontItems) {
        Install-Font -fontFile $FontItem.FullName
    }
   ```